# Цикл для классов

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, циклы

Доброй ночи, у меня есть класс User, не могу понять как верно использовать цикл для классов. Хотел создать цикл, чтобы инкремент увеличивался только до определенного числа вне класса. Но мне выдала такую ошибку TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'. Я так понимаю что он мой метод должен что-то возвращать чтобы работать с циклом или же нет? Заранее благодарю вас за помощь

```
class User():

    def __init__(self,first_name,last_name,age,city):
        """Инициализация атрибутов"""
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name  = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.city = city
        self.login_attempts = 0

    def describe_user(self):
        """Вывод некоторой информации о пользователе"""
        print("Имя пользователя: " + self.first_name)
        print("Фамилия пользователя: " + self.last_name)
        print("Возраст: " + self.age)
        print("Родной город: " + self.city)

    def greet_user(self):
        print("\n Hello " + self.first_name.title())

    def increment_login_attempts(self):
        self.login_attempts += 1

 

log = User('Иван','Иванович','21','Иваново')
while log.increment_login_attempts() < 5:
    log.increment_login_attempts()
print(log.login_attempts)
```

Comment: `
def increment_login_attempts(self,x,login = 0):
        while login < x:
            self.login_attempts += 1
            login += 1
`
Вот, что делал в методе. Но есть ли решение вне класса?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос. Вы должны что-то возвращать (иначе вернётся `None`). Можете возвращать количество попыток:

```py
def increment_login_attempts(self):
    self.login_attempts += 1
    return self.login_attempts
```

Но более предпочтительно, на мой взгляд, изменить цикл:

```py
while log.login_attempts < 5:
    log.increment_login_attempts()
```